# How to use "_" underscore in foreach loop to build range

Tags: perl, for-loop, foreach, range

I have a hash with indexes like "Bonus", "Plusbonus", "Plusbonus_001", "Plusbonus_001", ...

Now I'm looking for a possibility to handle these keys in a loop. (But, there are many others not to handle!)

I tried

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for ("Bonus", "Plusbonus", "Plusbonus_001" .. "Plusbonus_010") {
  # do some stuff
}
```

But I get the error `Argument "Plusbonus_001" isn't numeric in range (or flop) at ./test.pl line 14.`

Without the `_`/underscore it works well.

I used

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

for ("", "001" .. "010") {
  my $index = "Plusbonus" . ($_ ? "_$_" : "");
  # do some stuff by using $index instead of $_ as key
}
```

But now, with "Bonus", there is another key to handle so that my workaround doesn't work anymore.

Is there a possibility to generate these keys on another short way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the spirit of using the magic string increment as attempted, you can use the following. It's short but not easy to read.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

for ("Bonus", "Plusbonus", map { "Plusbonus_" . $_ } "001" .. "010") {
  # do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, great - but I can save some parantheses :) `for ("Bonus", "Plusbonus", map { "Plusbonus" . $_} "001" .. ""010")` works too and its easier to read, I think.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [map](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map) to build a range:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

for (map { sprintf 'Plusbonus_%03d', $_ } 0 .. 10) {
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
Plusbonus_000
Plusbonus_001
Plusbonus_002
Plusbonus_003
Plusbonus_004
Plusbonus_005
Plusbonus_006
Plusbonus_007
Plusbonus_008
Plusbonus_009
Plusbonus_010
```

Comment: Works fine with the addition of ("Bonus", "Plusbonus", map { ....) before map.